# Statement scope variable in while and do-while iterations?

Tags: c#, scope, iteration

I'm wondering about the iteration constructions in C# (but I guess this would also apply to C++ and Java).

```
class Program {
    static void Main (string[] args) {

        // With 'for' i is in statement scope only
        for (int i = 0; i <= 3;) { Console.WriteLine(i++); }
        Console.WriteLine ("Control variable i is not accessible\n");

        // No statement scope for 'while'
        int j = 0;
        while (j <= 3) { Console.WriteLine (j++); }
        Console.WriteLine ($"Control variable after loop: {j}\n");  // Possible

        // No statement scope for 'do-while'
        int k = 0;
        do { Console.WriteLine (k++); } while (k <= 3);
        Console.WriteLine ($"Control variable after loop: {k}\n"); // Possible
    }
}
```

In the `for` iteration, variable `i` is available in the embedded statement, in the control part of the statement, but not outside the `for` statement. It's scope is therefore the statement itself.

However it doesn't seem possible to have such scoping with `while` and `do-while` iterations. The control variable cannot be declared/initialized in the control part of the statements. If it is declared within the embedded statement, it's not visible in the control part (the code cannot compile), and if it's declared outside the whole statement it's visible outside the statement, in no way comparable to the control variable of the `for` iteration construction.

The above is indeed logical, however I would like to know:

- if there is a way to declare a variable in `while` and `do-while` which would be visible in the embedded statement, in the control portion, but not outside the statement, like the `int i` of the `for` statement.
- if not, is there an obvious reason the designers didn't allow it?

Comment: They didn't allow it because that's not how it works in C. It doesn't work that way in C because C only had such on-the-fly initialization in `for` statements, presumably because declaring temporaries for this purpose was so common. Note that for both C and C#, the rules for the scoping of the variable have changed between releases of the language; the scope being "local" is a recent innovation, and in early versions it was actually available after the loop (ultimately considered a Bad Idea). If you want a local scope, you can always introduce it explicitly: `{ int j = 0; while (...) }`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: I just didn't think about creating a scope with `{...}`. Indeed.

Comment: "Statements that introduce an identifier with a scope" was an idea that was expanded on in later languages (including C#), with such things as `using (var x = ...)`, `foreach (var x in ...)` and `fixed (var x =  ...)`, so now it's "idiomatic" in some sense, but in C there was only `for` doing it (and even then without actually restricting the scope, until later versions). The value of somehow retrofitting this into existing control statements would be limited compared to the potential syntactic confusion of such expressions and the loss of "compatibility" with other C-likes.